# Tkinter:Matrix Addition or Deduction Buttons

Tags: python, matrix, tkinter

I have a problem with my code. I want to create a program using Tkinter in which you will give a specific number of columns and raws and then pressing the button Addition or Deduction you will choose what you want to do. Here is my code

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
root.wm_geometry("400x300+20+40")
class ADialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        Label(top, text="X").pack()
        self.e = Entry(top)   #RAWS
        self.e.pack(padx=15)
        Label(top, text="Y").pack()
        self.w = Entry(top)   #COLUMNS
        self.w.pack(padx=15)
        b = Button(top, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.pack(pady=5) 
    def ok(self):
        self.x = self.e.get()
        self.y = self.w.get()
        Label(root,text="X= "+ self.x).pack()
        Label(root,text="Y= "+ self.y).pack()
        self.top.destroy()
        Button(root, text="Addition", command=lambda:Addition(int(self.x),int(self.y))).pack() #ADDITION BUTTON
        Button(root, text="Deduction", command=lambda:Deduction(int(self.x),int(self.y))).pack() # DEDUCTION BUTTON
def Addition(x,y):
    for i in range(x):
        c=[]
        for j in range(y):
            c.append(random.randint(10,100))
        M.append(c)
    for i in range(x):
        a=[]
        for j in range(y):
            a.append(random.randint(10,100))           
        N.append(a)
    for i in range(x):
        v=[]
        for j in range(y):
            v.append(M[i][j]+N[i][j])
    K.append(v)
    for i in range(x):
        Label(root,text=K[i]).pack()
def Deduction(x,y):
    for i in range(x):
        c=[]
        for j in range(y):
            c.append(random.randint(10,100))            
        M.append(c)
    for i in range(x):
        a=[]
        for j in range(y):
            a.append(random.randint(10,100))            
        N.append(a)
    for i in range(x):
        v=[]
        for j in range(y):
            v.append(M[i][j]-N[i][j])
    K.append(v)
    for i in range(x):
        Label(root,text=K[i]).pack()


M=[]
N=[]
K=[]
message=StringVar()
message.set("Complete the Matrix")
Label(root, textvariable=message).pack(padx=30)
root.update()
dial = ADialog(root)
root.wait_window(dial.top)
message.set("Matrix completed")
root.update()
root.mainloop()
Button(root, text="Done", command=root.destroy).pack() #Button Done
```

Now my code is working but with some problems.
These are:

1. If you press the button Deduction or Addition you will get your result but then if you try to press the other button you will get the same result.
2. The button "Done" never appears...

Can you help me?

Comment: I had a little error but I fixed it. However the problem remains the same. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Done" button never appears because you create it after mainloop exits, and then your program exits immediately after you create it. You need to create all widgets before calling `mainloop`.

With the code you posted I don't see how it's possible for both Addition and Deduction buttons can call the same function. So, if you are getting the same results, both functions must be doing the exact same thing.